# Create a matrix of weight which sum to one efficiently

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, iteration

I am creating a linear combinations generator and tester. The objective is to test all linear combinations of N inputs to identify which produces the optimal score.

Creating the matrix of weights can be done in a forceful way, as below. However, this is not flexible in an application when there can be 2+ modules with no upper limit. Is there a way to generalise this code?

It would also be ideal to have this output in matrix form so I can simply multiply the input matrix with a scalar to get the linear combination output!

Edit: To be completely explicit. I am looking for a way to flexibly reference

```
for i in range...: 
   for j in range...: 
       for k in range...
```

to be for 2, 3, 4, + modules

```
def generate_weights(n=4, min_weight=0, max_weight=100):
    weight_dictionary = {}
    combination = 1
    for i in range(0, 101):
        for j in range(0, 101):
            for k in range(0, 101):
                for l in range(0, 101):
                    # For now, ignoring conditions on each individual scalar's min and max weight criteria
                    if i + j + k + l == 100:
                        weight_dictionary[combination] = (i, j, k, l)
                        combination+=1
    return weight_dictionary

test = generate_weights()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often the easiest way to cope with an unknown depth of stacked loops is to use recursion.  Each time the function runs it runs one loop, the recursion depth gives the stacking.

```
import numpy as np

def generate_weights0( layers = 4, tgt = 100 ):
    """ Generate list of lists with 'layers' items adding to tgt """
    result = []

    def one_layer( layers, tgt, cumul ):
        """  layers: layers still to produce.
             tgt: the tgt still left to be consumed.
             cumul: a list of the combinations for the layers already processed.
        """
        if layers == 1: # return results for the last layer
            cumul.append( tgt )
            result.append( cumul )
        else:
            # For each i call one_layer with revised parameters
            for i in range( tgt + 1 ):
                cumul_ = cumul.copy()
                cumul_.append( i )
                # Recursive call with updated parameters
                one_layer( layers - 1, tgt - i, cumul_ )

    one_layer( layers, tgt, [] )  # Execute the initialised function
    return np.array( result )
```

Above returns the results assuming min is zero.  To avoid complexity there's a second function which calls the above having adjusted the parameters for the minimum value.  It then adds the minimum value to all the result.

```
def generate_weights( layers = 4, min_ = 0, tgt = 100 ):
    tgt = tgt - ( layers * min_ )
    return generate_weights0( layers, tgt ) + min_
```

I think this returns what you intended.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. if you have any suggested resources on recursion and when to use it, I would like to study this!

Comment: I first used recursion in the 1980s so I'm not the best person to ask.  Try searching for recursive algorithms. Wikipedia may help as it's an approach to finding solutions rather than being too language specific. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Because of "i + j + k + l == 100", you don't need calculate range 0~100 every times,you can limit the range and exclude the values impossible, like this:

```
    for i in range(0, 101):
        for j in range(0, 101-i):
            for k in range(0, 101-i-j):
                for l in range(0, 101-i-j-k):
```

time complexity before:O(n**4)

```
>>> test = generate_weights()
Time:  12.879271500000016
```

time complexity after:O(n*log(n))

```
>>> test = generate_weights()
Time:  0.6409992999999758
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the optimisation! I am currently focusing on a way to change writing manually "for i in range... for j in range... for k in range..." to some dynamic reference to an array and loop through that or a list to achieve the same result.